# 3.9+ extend any become extend unknow

Tags: typescript

3.9 [This is intended change Type Parameters That Extend any No Longer Act as any](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#type-parameters-that-extend-any-no-longer-act-as-any)

my code has some error message

> Type 'P' cannot be used to index type 'S'.(2536)

How can I modify this type code  **ReplaceValByOwnKey**

```
type ReplaceValByOwnKey<T extends any, S extends any> = { [P in keyof T]: S[P] };

// shift action
type ShiftAction<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => any) extends ((arg1: any, ...rest: infer R) => any) ? R : never;

// unshift action
type UnshiftAction<T extends any[], A> = ((args1: A, ...rest: T) => any) extends ((...args: infer R) => any) ? R : never;

// pop action
type PopAction<T extends any[]> = ReplaceValByOwnKey<ShiftAction<T>, T>

// push action
type PushAction<T extends any[], E> = ReplaceValByOwnKey<UnshiftAction<T, any>, T & { [k: string]: E }>;

// test ...
type tuple = ['vue', 'react', 'angular'];

type resultWithShiftAction = ShiftAction<tuple>; // ["react", "angular"]
type resultWithUnshiftAction = UnshiftAction<tuple, 'jquery'>; // ["jquery", "vue", "react", "angular"]
type resultWithPopAction = PopAction<tuple>; // ["vue", "react"]
type resultWithPushAction = PushAction<tuple, 'jquery'>;
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#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-5QvQ0vd6522eF6dsA972PmUAjmOL6yu+UAyh4X6LsuqYHoM25ekKKwOEAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without delving too far into your use case, I'd say the right thing to do here is probably to use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to check if `S` can be indexed by `P` and to only do the indexing if so.  It's up to you what you want to do if it can't be indexed like that (below I am returning `any`, but `never` is also reasonable):

```
type ReplaceValByOwnKey<T extends any, S extends any> = 
  { [P in keyof T]: P extends keyof S ? S[P] : any };
```

This should silence the error inside the definition and not change any behavior at least in cases where `S[P]` does exist (e.g., your example code output stays the same).

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsCGBjCA1JCBCIDyA7gHYDSEIAPACpQQAewERAJgM5RJEgA0UAyrQZM2HLgD4oAXigBvKAG0AClACWRKAGtyAewBmUKgF0AXFGX1GLdlpB7+UAPz8lhqKc4goAXwDcAWAAoQMCAehCoVgALFV1gDhRgFW0iQNBIfmjYgEEEpKJqQUsRD3lDCWkACgqAOlqkACcAc1ZTKgBKKQkPDothdiqGxoBGdy5eWur6iFZgUzVdCHrYDskurg6nGDcoIggAN0X-IICwqABXIiiYuNRE5NTwaABVS8zgHLv8ml6rURBS3hZcpQAZNVgjKBZca1KYzVorNYgHpCX5VCaDFqqIgLJYwBF-Dawba7A71I6hcJgbRgeKfB7pRTUj55Ao-YpcUrAuCIVAYLC4QikcgUPhvZnJahiXhUMTBE6Us5RWl5enQRSKyLir6FPp-AFQACiXPgyDQmBw+GIZEoLyu2VyEqovA8UoMUAAZLIFBpTDN6mpGiZDd4xOT5VBGDMoBNVRGzohoNJ5AByPZnCDJ3jJqa3TNQZOcRpnZD1ZOGMNpaCw4vAADqKmAkVF1y1UgyLYd+WA8YQEFDUFO8gARDmEkPeEPC8WGkPDLHqwg6w3IraxZ226uO58KN2E1mAFYAR3T9RAyf7g6HR5PIHHUCHaYgd5HEFuz6nJdn8+mNfrjcZYCttIAFajuPZ9j4A7hMOj7PqOwBfgElZQAuS7-hqQFmBhnZgXu+bXosZ4XtBD7pnBr5jhOH4zhOBGnohcqBEAA)